# Was the Fellowship supposed to visit Galadriel originally?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In Gandalf's and co original plan (pre-Moria), was the Fellowship supposed to visit Lothlórien and meet Galadriel?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It does seem that way (emphasis mine):

> **I shall take you by the road that Gandalf chose**, and first I hope to come to the woods where the Silverlode flows into the Great River-out yonder.' They looked as [Aragorn] pointed, and before them they could see the stream leaping down to the trough of the valley, and then running on and away into the lower lands, until it was lost in a golden haze.
>
> 'There lie the woods of Lothlórien!' said Legolas.
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 6: "Lothlórien"</sup>
>
> 'Your quest is known to us,' said Galadriel, looking at Frodo. 'But we will not here speak of it more openly. Yet not in vain will it prove, maybe, that **you came to this land seeking aid, as Gandalf himself plainly purposed**.
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 7: "The Mirror of Galadriel"</sup>
>
> [I]s all this Company going with you to Minas Tirith?'
>
> 'We have not decided our course,' said Aragorn. '**Beyond Lothlórien I do not know what Gandalf intended to do**. Indeed I do not think that even he had any clear purpose.'
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 8: "Farewell to Lórien"</sup>

It's also implied that Elrond's sons were sent to Lothlórien as part of the scouting effort:

> The sons of Elrond, Elladan and Elrohir, were the last to return; they had made a great journey, passing down the Silverlode into a strange country, but of their errand they would not speak to any save to Elrond.
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 3: "The Ring Goes South"</sup>